# Firestore - How to retrieve all subcollections of a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question regarding Firestore,
I created a "category" collection in which I have several documents, I created a "construction sites" sub-collection!
I want to retrieve all my sub collections from each category, but when I try to do like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const listConstruction = [];

    db.collection('category').get().then((collectionCategory) => {
      collectionCategory.forEach((doc) => {
        doc.ref.collection('construction').get().then((collectionConstruction) => {
          collectionConstruction.forEach((doc1) => {
            listConstruction.push({
              idCategory: doc.id,
              libelleCategory: doc.data().libelle,
              title: doc1.data().title,
              description: doc1.data().description,
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }).finally(() => {
      setConstruction(listConstruction);
    });
 }, []);
```

The problem is that it hasn't finished pushing the constructs it passes into my finally!

Having no experience with NoSQL and Firestore yet, I would have liked if I'm not completely wrong about its use and if so how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, you need to use a [Collection Group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection_group).

As explained in the doc:

> A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID. By default, queries retrieve results from a single collection in your
> database. Use a collection group query to retrieve documents from a
> collection group instead of from a single collection.

---

Side note: If you want to call **asynchronous** methods in a `forEach` loop, you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: if I use the collection group, I will have the data of my "construction" table but how can I create an object of the form:
{
idCategory: ...
labelCategory: ...
titleConstruction: ...
descriptionConstruction: ...
} Since it will only return the information of the documents present in my sub-collection

Comment: One standard approach is to duplicate the data of the parent in the children documents in the sub-collections. You could, for each doc in a sub-collection, fetch the data of its parent, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70530231/3371862), but this mean that you'll triggered a lot of fetch to the DB. In NoSQL world, it is very common to duplicate data in order to easily write your queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the first time I have made a NOSQL database. Following your answer, I have a question if I modify my parent element, I will have to rewrite in all my child elements?

Comment: "if I modify my parent element, I will have to rewrite in all my child elements? " You'll have to update all the child elements. A common approach is to use a Cloud Function for that, which runs in the back-end and is triggered each time a parent doc is updated.